# Flask EqualTo validator, where to define password2

Tags: python, flask

I'm following the Flask Web Development book but running in to an issue with the following code:

```
class RegistrationForm(Form):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[Required(),
                        Length(1, 64), Email()])
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[Required(),
                           Regexp('^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*$', 0,
                           'Usernames must have only letters, numbers,'
                                  'underscores or dots')])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[Required(),
                             EqualTo(password2,
                             message="Passwords must match")])
    password2 = PasswordField('Confirm password', validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Register')
```

In the book `password2` is defined after `password`, this leads to the error: `NameError: name 'password2' is not defined`. What is going on here? How should I define `password2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote it

```
password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[Required(),
                         EqualTo('password2',
                         message="Passwords must match")])
```